# Is it possible to get chart js data using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to get data of chart JS using AJAX. I've searched all forums including stackoverflow but none of them seem to work. Here is my code.

```
var chartData = {};

function respondCanvas() {
    new Chart(document.getElementById("exampleChartjsLine").getContext("2d")).Line(chartData);
}


var GetChartData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/control-panel/actions/saleStatistic.php",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {command: "authorsGrid"}
    }).done(function (data) {
        var chartData = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            scaleShowGridLines: true,
            scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
            scaleGridLineColor: "#ebedf0",
            datasets: [{
                fillColor: "rgba(204, 213, 219, .1)",
                strokeColor: $.colors("blue-grey", 300),
                pointColor: $.colors("blue-grey", 300),
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: $.colors("blue-grey", 300),
                data: data
            }, {
                fillColor: "rgba(98, 168, 234, .1)",
                strokeColor: $.colors("primary", 600),
                pointColor: $.colors("primary", 600),
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: $.colors("primary", 600),
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
            }]
        };
        respondCanvas();
    });
};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        GetChartData();
    });
```

What I'm getting is this error from console log:

[Console Log Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a65oY.png)

Ajax call returns array in Javascript just like it should be in chart js:

[Ajax Callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5DDY.png)

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

----- UPDATE (according to answer by Quince) -----

```
var chartData = {};

function respondCanvas(data) {
    new Chart(document.getElementById("exampleChartjsLine").getContext("2d")).Line(data);
}



var GetChartData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/control-panel/actions/saleStatistic.php",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {command: "authorsGrid"},
        success: function(data) {
           chartData = {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                scaleShowGridLines: true,
                scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
                scaleGridLineColor: "#ebedf0",
                datasets: [{
                    fillColor: "rgba(204, 213, 219, .1)",
                    strokeColor: $.colors("blue-grey", 300),
                    pointColor: $.colors("blue-grey", 300),
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: $.colors("blue-grey", 300),
                    data: data
                }, {
                    fillColor: "rgba(98, 168, 234, .1)",
                    strokeColor: $.colors("primary", 600),
                    pointColor: $.colors("primary", 600),
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: $.colors("primary", 600),
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                }]
           };
           respondCanvas(chartData);
        }
    });
};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        GetChartData();
    });
```

Comment: Are you using IE8 or later?

Comment: @KamilMierzyński Yes I'm using Opera.

Comment: @KamilMierzyński I've checked it on other browsers too and it's not working there either. So something different must be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `chartData` twice, the one used inside `reposondCanvas` is not the one you are writing to in `done`. Either pass the `chartData` as a parameter to`respondCanvas` and remove the global refence (I would recommend this if you do not need to continually update the data) or remove `var` from your second declaration

Comment: I did as you've said but now I don't get any error but still an empty space in chart area. I'll update code.

Comment: Wow I finally got it fixed after using json.parse. Anyway thanks for your help. Without your advice, code wouldn't have worked at all.